# Navigation: bundle in startDestination is null

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I have HomeFragment, which includes RecyclerView. When I click on an item, I want to go from HomeFragment in `navigation/home_navigation.xml` to another DictionaryFragment, which is located in `navigation/dictionary_navigation.xml`, where DictionaryFragment is a **startDestination**.

I've created a new action to nested `navigation/dictionary_navigation.xml` graph because I need to open startDestination:

[image: Nested graph]

I don't know, how to transfer my data to *DictionaryFragment* correctly, but this:

**HomeFragment**

```kotlin
wordPackAdapter = PackAdapter(context, Utils.dictionaryPacks) {
    val bundle = Bundle().apply {
        putInt("packId", it.index)
    }
    navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_dictionary_navigation, bundle)
}
```

**DictionaryFragment**

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val bundle = requireActivity().intent.extras <---- null
}
```

**Extensions**

```kotlin
fun BaseFragment.navigate(
    resId: Int,
    bundle: Bundle? = null,
    navOptions: NavOptions? = null
) {
    NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(resId, bundle, navOptions)
}
```

doesn't work, because *bundle is null*.

I also use SafeArgs plugin, but as I know, I can't use *DictionaryFragmentArgs.fromBundle()* with a startDestination.

How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess on DictionaryFragment you should try to fetch the data with `getArguments()`